# A bit rusty on c, how do I print useful information of this structure?

Tags: c

So I'm trying to debug a linux module someone else wrote and it's a while since I wrote anything in c/c++

I get an error here (this question is indirectly related to the error):

```
video_register_device(usbMightex->vdev, VFL_TYPE_GRABBER, video_nr)
```

so I wanted to try and find out what `usbMightex->vdev` is.

This it's structure:

http://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/legacy/video4linux/v4l2dwgNew.html

struct video_device

```
char name[32]                              :Canonical name for this device.
int type                                   :Type of V4L2 device
(use type2 as well, look at videodev2.h for details on type2)
int minor                                  :The device's minor number
struct file_operations *fops;              :File operations used, which are displayed below
void (*release)(struct video_device *vfd); :Release function used by the driver to release
void *priv:                                :Can be used by the driver
```

I already have a `pr_err` statement that is used to print information but not sure how to use it. Not sure where it's defined. I think I'll be happy with a simple printf statement or smth similar so I can then pick up the output with `dmesg`

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

A commenter asked for some more information with regards to the error:

I have posted a different question about the problem generally here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/565700/how-do-i-load-a-module-that-has-no-signature-in-ubuntu-12-04

This question is NOT about the error, it was merely about how to print some information that would potentially be useful in solving the error. Thank you to all that responded.

Comment: why close? What's wrong with the question?

Comment: Perhaps `printf("name: %s\ntype: %d\nminor: %d\n", vd.name, vd.type, vd.minor` (where `vd` is a `video_device`)? The `file_operations` member is just a bunch of function pointers, so unless you want to do a hex dump of pointer values, that's about all the useful information I can suggest for printing.

Comment: where `vc` I use `usbMightex->vdev` right?

Comment: probably not... I removed the tag.

Comment: @evan54: "I get an error here". What error? Perhaps copy that into your question. Perhaps provide a full example that we could compile to also produce the error?

Comment: @BillLynch I'll try to add some useful information in the question, though due to my limited knowledge I doubt I'll be able to provide enough for you to reproduce the error.

Comment: @BillLynch Actually instead of convoluting this question with what triggers the error I added a reference to a different question where I'm asking for help with the problem itself. Let me know if you want more info with regards to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious answer is, use a debugger and put a breakpoint where you want to see the variables.

To print out in code then, assuming your linked page is correct (you should verify this by checking the header file, otherwise nonsense output may ensue):

```
printf("%31s\n", v->name);
printf("%d\n", v->type);
printf("%d\n", v->minor);
printf("%p\n", (void *)v->fops);
printf(PRIxMAX "\n", (uintmax_t)v->release);
printf("%p\n", priv);
```

where `v` is the pointer to the instance of the structure.

Comment: I only know how to run this by restarting the computer :( Its a kernel module for a webcam and I know near to nothing about kernel modules. I got the `v->name` statement work. I'm now trying the rest

Comment: thank you so much! I looked for the header file and found it in the end here: `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-43/include/media/v4l2-dev.h` and indeed it was a bit different but you got me going!

Answer (score 1):

If it is compiled as kernel module (*.ko), you could probably insert and remove it multiple times without reboot

`lsmod`, `modprobe`, `insmod` etc

And you might find useful `printk()` functions, they output to syslog which goes into `dmesg` IIRC

Comment: I'm currently using `pr_err()` no idea where that is defined but seems to work pretty much the same as what you said. Also, care to elaborate on the `modprobe`, `insmod`, `lsmod`? I tried doing a `modprobe myModule* but it didn't do anything... :s

Comment: nice! got it working, did `rmmod myMod` and `insmod myMod` and got the messages on `dmesg`